# Synchronise Radiobutton Selection with Row selection in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, radio-button, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a RadioButtonTemplateColumn in my datagrid. When the radiobutton is clicked, the corresponding row gets selected, but when the row is clicked the corresponding radiobutton is not selected. This leaves the system in a 'confused' state as the radiobutton and row selection are not in sync. Please how do I synchronise them? I have reviewed a similar response but it did not resolve the issue or me.

Below is the code I have written:

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="Select" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your binding is invalid. If you use a tool like [Snoop Wpf](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) or the live visual tree in Visual Studio, you'll see that your binding isn't working.

The reason why is that your `RadioButton` is inside a template which has the data context of the data that the grid is bound to - not the `DataGridRow`. If you update your binding like so, it will work:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Essentially, I told the binding to look for `IsSelected` relative to the `DataGridRow` higher up in the visual tree.

Another problem is that because you're using a `RadioButton` it cannot be un-selected when clicking on it. If you want it to act like a toggle, you should use a `CheckBox` instead.

I hope this helps.